# During Git Rebase, at what point do conflict resolutions get committed when using --continue

Tags: git, git-rebase

We are running git rebase and running into conflicts, where we need to use --continue after we resolve merge conflicts. However, I am accustom to manually running the commit once the conflicts are resolved. Since we don't see additional commits when the entire rebase completes, at what point do conflict resolutions get committed?

Answer (score 2):

Any conflict resolutions that occur during a rebase will belong to the new commit that the rebase creates.

So the direct answer to the question:

> what point do conflict resolutions get committed?

...is after `--continue`, but effectively after the entire rebase command completes and your branch pointer is updated.

From an outsider's perspective a branch that has been rebased looks like the work was done immediately after branching and had no need for any conflict resolution because work was performed on top of that content.

This is sometimes preferable to a merge because the commit history can be easier to reason about if there are not as many (possibly) meaningless merge-commits

Answer (score 2):

It helps to think of a rebase as just writing a new sequence of commits, reapplying the commits being rebased on top of a new head. If each commit can be applied automatically, great, make it so. When a commit cannot be applied automatically, `git` tells you, leaves the index as best as it can be represented, with the conflicting files appropriately marked, then after you tell it to continue the rebase, things proceed as follows:

If `git rebase --continue` finds uncommitted changes in the index, it presumes that the changes constitute the resolved conflicts, and commits it. It prompts for a commit message, and uses it for that commit, then resumes rebasing the remaining commits, after the one that originally caused a conflict.

If `git rebase --continue` sees nothing uncommitted, it presumes that the conflict has been manually resolved and committed, so it simply continues with the remaining commits in the rebase.

Comment: everything makes sense except for this part: "It prompts for a commit message, and uses it for that commit". We don't get prompted for a commit message.

Thanks for the help